# Calculating throughput in lte network simulation in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I want to calculate throughput, packet loss and other network parameters in an lte network that I simulate in ns3. I can get 3 trace files as results: one for Mac trace, Rlc trace, and Pdcp.

In ns3 website, the trace part for lte is empty!
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.10/manual/html/lte.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand in which part you refer to, as there is no 'trace' section in the LTE manual. Also, use the latest version of ns-3 documentation, and not one from ns-3.10 (almost 5 yr old).

Specifically, for [LTE output](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/lte-user.html#simulation-output) there is a section explaining what these file you get contain. You would then to analyse those files to get total throughput or other statistics.

In addition to the LTE specific output, you can use FlowMonitor and/or the data collection framework (both explained in the ns-3 manual) and with examples available in the codebase.